# Facepile embedded with email

Tags: facebook, email, facepile

Interested to find out how to embed data from facebook such as a "facepile" into an email that is generated server side. Can only find doco on adding to a web page.

Realise the email can not using javascript to grab realtime data in the email but interested in grabbing a snap shot in time of the "facepile" and adding that to an email.
ie static content

Also interested in doing the same thing with a facebook "activity feed".

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes, but it's incredibly unlikely that any email client will render client-side javascript or iframes, which means effectively there's no point in trying to do this as best-case scenario is that the majority of people will get a broken email, and the rest will have the email automatically blocked or deleted because of the javascript

Comment: Yes - realise that is javascript is not an option - more looking for a solution to get the data and store offline then add this to the email

Comment: Well you could do it manually I guess, but then the question becomes very vague - it'd be up to your app to assemble all the relevant data from the api, which depends entirely on what data you want

Comment: not manually - want to create an email on the fly with this data from facebook - the sample code is for a webpage - want to know how to add it to an email with code dynamically

Comment: When i said manually i meant that instead of relying on some prebuilt solution, you'd need to do this in your app's code, not by hand